# class does not exist: Mapreduce program in terminal

Tags: java, class, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a mapreduce program beginner.
I am trying to run a mapreduce program via. ubuntu terminal.
while running the program i met with this error.

/home/hduser/myprograms/tables/SmsDriver.java:4: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;

please help me..

Comment: Could you please show me your command?

Comment: javac -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar /home/hduser/myprograms/tables/SmsDriver.java

Answer (score 0):

The command to run a job is **bin/hadoop jar**. And you must have **hadoop-core-*.jar** in your classpath while compiling the job.

**javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar**

And to run the job :

**bin/hadoop jar /path/to/your/file.jar MainClass /path/to/input /path/to/output**